# OpenLayers - Setting View Correctly Extent GEOJSon

Tags: javascript, openlayers

So I have a geoJSON Object that I retrieve from a databsae. For this example I gave a couple points of the object here. But IF you see the map is so var zoomed out It makes this thing useless. I have this working from a qgis to web. But I am trying to build a streamlined and programmatic version of this.  to read the geojson and certain properties they want to pass. Then display it. I put together this very rudimentary jsfiddle. Can someone please help.

```
var extent = vectorSource.getExtent();
console.log(extent);
map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nextgenmappinginc/pkuj4jyh/

Edit: Another Fork

https://jsfiddle.net/nextgenmappinginc/zen0qu5e/

-

As Always

I appreciate your help

Comment: Note I have added a second fork of this. Where view becomes an object that's being passed. So it can be access as well. 

tried setting a different way. But still having much trouble.

Comment: cross-posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255887/openlayers-setting-view-correctly-extent-geojson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember about Coordinate Reference Systems. In this case Web Mercator, EPSG: 3857. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrkf38ak/)

```
var layer1 = JSON.parse("{\r\n\"type\": \"FeatureCollection\",\r\n\"crs\": { \"type\": \"name\", \"properties\": { \"name\": \"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84\" } },\r\n\"features\": [\r\n{ \"type\": \"Feature\", \"properties\": { \"SCAN\": \"ATT000\", \"X_ft\": 281.911818, \"Y_ft\": 54.100892, \"Z_ft\": 5.418261, \"r\": -0.0016141, \"g\": 0.000225555, \"b\": 0.99999867, \"i\": 168.802, \"date\": \"10.12.2012\", \"time\": \"10:00:54\", \"X_in\": 3382.941816, \"Y_in\": 649.210704, \"Z_in\": 65.019132 }, \"geometry\": { \"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [ -141.20886083733603, 30.013650297314303 ] } },\r\n{ \"type\": \"Feature\", \"properties\": { \"SCAN\": \"ATT001\", \"X_ft\": 282.505798, \"Y_ft\": 44.299598, \"Z_ft\": 5.313561, \"r\": 0.001370681, \"g\": -0.000725627, \"b\": -0.9999988, \"i\": 97.710151, \"date\": \"10.12.2012\", \"time\": \"10:11:32\", \"X_in\": 3390.069576, \"Y_in\": 531.595176, \"Z_in\": 63.762732 }, \"geometry\": { \"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [ -141.20875820820822, 30.0133417954119 ] } },\r\n{ \"type\": \"Feature\", \"properties\": { \"SCAN\": \"ATT002\", \"X_ft\": 271.674014, \"Y_ft\": 53.557958, \"Z_ft\": 5.26399, \"r\": -0.003173992, \"g\": -0.003689405, \"b\": 0.99998816, \"i\": 43.906879, \"date\": \"10.12.2012\", \"time\": \"10:22:08\", \"X_in\": 3260.088168, \"Y_in\": 642.695496, \"Z_in\": 63.16788 }, \"geometry\": { \"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [ -141.2092317486329, 30.013559475335278 ] } }]}");
var image = new ol.style.Circle({
  radius: 5,
  fill: null,
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'red', width: 1})
});
var styles = {
  'Point': new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      fill:new ol.style.Fill({color: 'red'}),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'black', width: 1}),
      radius: 4
    })
  })
};
var styleFunction = function(feature) {
  return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
};
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(layer1, {
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
  })
});
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: styleFunction
});
var view =  new ol.View({
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 100
});
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  view: view
});
map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent(), map.getSize())
```

Comment: thank you very much. I am totally new to this. I have moved past this point and started diving into a much deeper function. Care to help out with that one? Running into issue with url of geojson

Comment: @NextGenDevelopment If you provide a jsfiddle, I will try :)

Comment: Ok, I give up. I have tried and tried. This thing as a 1000x more times complex. but even now it doesn't work. MOST BASIC. But trying to load from url

I have private urls but using public just to test
https://jsfiddle.net/nextgenmappinginc/qeb53o3b/

Comment: Ok, so I can give you a hint: in [documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html) you have specified "Note that if a source contains non-feature data, such as a GeoJSON geometry or a KML NetworkLink, these will be ignored.". Try to do an AJAX and then create map and layers with specified geometry. If you will have more problems, we will solve it.

Comment: P.S. I have switched it over to version 3 and still with same result.